# Can I rename a horse after it has been registered?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I caught and registered a Giant Horse in Tears of the Kingdom. However, I don't like the name I gave it. it possible to change the name of a horse after it has been registered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, no. Many people are complaining about that on Reddit, too.
As far as I know the only "solution" is to release the horse and catch it again. Rare horses should spawn again in the same location you originally found them.