# Can I find unregistered unique horses again after I completed their related quest?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Suppose I complete a horse related quest, like "Zelda's Golden Horse" or "Spotting Spot", and decide to not register the horse on the spot. Does the horse permanently disappear from the game, or can I find it in the wild somewhere, perhaps where I first found it?

Comment: I like the quests with fun names, like 'Spotting Spot', 'Fell in a Well', and 'Out of the Inn'.

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to know this as well. I registered the golden horse, but I didn't realize you can register that spotted horse. I thought I was merely returning the horse back to the owner. I don't believe I had the opportunity to register.

Comment: @JeffMercado Oh, that's too bad. But good news - completing that quest is supposed to unlock spotted horses in the wild. Maybe you could try to search for Spot again and see if he's somewhere near Lookout Landing?

Comment: It looks like _the_ Spot is just out there in front of the entrance in the same spot. Lester at the stables even asks if I'd be willing to take him in my care. So if you missed out on the gold horse, you could check the same spot again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find unique horses again if they aren't registered. In my playthrough, I wanted to give the Giant Horse [a different nickname](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/402992/181240). After releasing it, I was able to find it again in the same spot I found it last time.